# Associate Field Customizer with existing field using feature framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, spfx, spfx-extensions, fieldcustomizers

According to [Field Customizer documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer#add-the-field-definition-to-the-solution-package-for-deployment) it is possible to associate it with existing SharePoint field using feature framework. But I am not able to make it work. I am trying to customize the "Name" column (internal name LinkFilename) and using below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Field ID="{5cc6dc79-3710-4374-b433-61cb4a686c12}"
        Name="LinkFilename"
        DisplayName="Name"
        Type="Computed"
        Min=""
        Required="FALSE"
        Group="Custom Columns"
        ClientSideComponentId="b48a795e-e8d9-47f0-85db-5573bdc9ef11">
   </Field>
</Elements>
```

Comment: can check following? 1.package-solution.json has features node with ClientSideComponentId association 2. if it is tenant scoped deployement, skipFeatureDeployment  is set to true.

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia It is not tenant scope deployemnt and yes package-solution.json has elements.xml file included with correct ClientSideComponentId in elements.xml

Comment: For debugging purpose, i would suggest try on some other column....I am suspecting as Name column is OOTB column, customization might not be possible as I see this is not available in Site column also _layouts/15/mngfield.aspx...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a limitation of SPFx's feature framework's that you can't associate field customizer to existing OOTB fields.

Reference - [Highlighting which page is the welcome page in a site](https://www.techmikael.com/2018/08/highlighting-which-page-is-welcome-page.html)

Having said that, you can associate Field Customizer extension to existing OOTB list columns or site columns by setting `ClientSideComponentId` property of column with value of FieldCustomizer Id which you get from the extension's manifest json file.

You can do as below:

```
Set-PnPField -Identity "LinkFilename" -List "Documents" 
-Values @{ClientSideComponentId=[GUID]"123b3c84-b9f6-49bd-ba46-c5a531825411"}
```

If you want to do that at the web level, you can remove the `List` parameter from the above code.

Do note: If you apply it at the web level, newly created document libraries will automatically get the customizer associated. However, for existing libraries, you will need to do a one time PS script execution with list parameter.

Comment: Thanks Gautam I performed few tests and this seems to be the case.